Unable to find pandas in docker
I am very new to docker. I can successfully run python files on my machine however Docker is unable to recognize the pandas library.
Here is my Docker file:
FROM python
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
CMD ["python3", "fisherlog_corrected.py"]

The error message is as follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/fisherlog_corrected.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

How to solve this?

You need to install any library dependencies you have inside the image too.  The container is an isolated environment and can't see libraries that only exist on the host.  This depends a little bit on the specific Python packaging tools you're using, but something like RUN pip install . will install everything listed in your pyproject.toml file.

It says "zsh: command not found: pip". I tried different suggestions available over internet but nothing seems woking.

fisherlog_corrected.py 中依赖了 pandas 需要提前安装。

SO is a English language site, please translate the non-English parts of your answer.
